# Angular forms - compute 2 input and display value with just update onchange

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I want to input two values in input element and compute them but not with submit button, but using change event. **How to do this?**

example html

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Input 1</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="input">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Input 2</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="reference">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Sum</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="difference">
    </div>
</form>
```

It should be like this, when i type `input 1 = 2` & `input 2 = 3`, automatically add the two inputs and result like to this `sum = 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `change` event on your inputs will call the summing function you are looking to execute.

To be explicit, insert `(change)=“sum()“` in your `input` tag and then define your `sum` function in your `component.ts`, like so:

component.html

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Input 1</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="input1" (change)="sum()" [(ngModel)]="input1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Input 2</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="input2" (change)="sum()" [(ngModel)]="input2">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Sum</label>
      <p>{{total}}</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-selector',
  templateUrl: './name.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./name.component.css']
})
export class NameOfComponent {
  total: number
  input1: number = 0
  input2: number = 0

  sum () {
    this.total = this.input1 + this.input2
  }
}
```

Comment: can you give me a sample code? should i put it inside a function on component.ts?

Comment: Reactive Forms or Template Forms?

Comment: using template forms

Comment: Ok, then include `[ngModel]=“name”` on the inputs too. Then you define those variables in your component and access them in your sum function.

Comment: `<div class="form-group">
      <label>Input 2</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="input2" [ngModel]="input2" (ngModelChange)="sum()">
    </div>`

`sum(): {
console.log(this.input2) // undefined
}`

Comment: Oh, sorry, typo: I should have said `[(ngModel)]="input2"` That will make the binding 2-way, and allow you to access the value immediately in your function.

Comment: Ok, my edited answer should be exactly what you're looking for. Maybe try out this course on Udemy: https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-guide-to-angular-2
I think there may be a $9.99 sale right now.

Answer (score 1):

you needn't use (change)="sum()". You can simply write {{input1+input2}}

```
<form>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="input1"  [(ngModel)]="input1">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="input2"  [(ngModel)]="input2">
      <p>{{input1+input2}}</p>
</form>
```